# Jupyter Notebook web scraping is not giving me any display

Tags: jupyter-notebook

```
url='https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=1&sess=1&pid=2000001149000&rp=99999'
response = requests.get(url)
status = response.status_code
if status == 200:
    page = response.text
    soup = bs(page)
else:
    print(f"Oops! Received status code {status}")


print(soup.prettify())

   card_level_rank_list = [ ]
card_level_rank = soup.find(class_='card_list')
for span in card_list.find_all(class_='t_row c_normal'):
    level_rank = span.find(class_='box_card_level_rank level').text.strip()
    card_name = span.text
    card_level_rank_list.append({'Card Name':card_name,'Card Level/Rank':level_rank})
card_level_rank_df = pd.DataFrame(card_level_rank_list)

card_level_rank_list
```

I am trying to get this program to work in Jupyter Notebook, not giving me any display. Looking through Inspect Element doesn't show any reason why this isn't working. What can I try next?